# React Native: Why is that rendering a flatList inside each item of another flatList both horizontally not working as expected?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios

I am trying to render a flatlist component such that each item in that flatlist is another flatlist.

The problem is because I want both the flatlists to be horizontal.

However the inner flatlist is not rendering horizontally within each item of the flatlist.

[Here is an image of what it turned out to be.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Leua9.png)

The code is here:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, View, FlatList } from 'react-native';

class Box extends Component {

  renderItems = ({ item }) => {
    return (
      <View style={{ height: 50, backgroundColor: 'red', marginBottom: 10 }}><Text>{item.value}</Text></View>
    );
  };

  renderSeparator = () => {
    return <View style={{ width: 10 }} />;
  }
  render() {
    const items = [{ value: 'ONE' }, { value: 'TWO' }, { value: 'THREE' }];

    return (
      <FlatList
        data={items}
        renderItem={this.renderItems}
        ItemSeparatorComponent={this.renderSeparator}
        horizontal
      />
    );
  }
}


export default class Test extends Component {

  renderSeparator = () => <View style={{ width: 20 }} />

  renderItems = ({ item }) => {
    return (
      <View style={{ margin: 10, padding: 20, alignItems: 'center', top: 100, backgroundColor: 'green' }}>
        <View style={{margin: 10}}>
          <Text>
            {item.value}
          </Text>
        </View>
        <Box />
      </View>
    );
  }
  render() {
    const items = [{ value: 'First' }, { value: 'Second' }, { value: 'Third' }, { value: 'Fourth' }];
    return (
      <FlatList
        data={items}
        renderItem={this.renderItems}
        ItemSeparatorComponent={this.renderSeparator}
        horizontal
      />
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Any Fix for this ? Am also facing the same

Comment: Unfortunately no. Just made a work around by implementing inner list with a map function instead.